# why malloc doesnot work in my c program?

Tags: c, malloc, sizeof

```
struct BOOK
{
    char name[120];
    char author[120];
    int  year[50];
};

int main (void)
{
    int          i;
    int          number;
    struct BOOK* books;

    number = 50000;

    printf("before \nsizeofbooks %d \n sizeofBOOK %d\n",
           sizeof(books), sizeof(struct BOOK));

    books = (struct BOOK*)malloc(sizeof(struct BOOK) * number);

    printf("sizeofbooks %d \n sizeofBOOK %d\n",
           sizeof(books), sizeof(struct BOOK));

    free(books);
    return 0;
}
```

the output is:

```
before
sizeofbooks 4
sizeofBOOK 440
after
sizeofbooks 4
sizeofBOOK 440
```

It always outputs 4, even if I write to a different array, but I would expect it to change. What am I doing wrong?

My os is winxp 32 bit and I use codeblocks.

Comment: [You should not cast the return of malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, you just misunderstand how things work.  Pointers are not arrays.

Comment: @JeffRSon: I preferred that dupe since it's more similar to this question (and the answers apply perfectly).

Comment: Note that `typedef struct { ... } Book;` would prevent having to write `struct` all the time. And it's nice to treat it as a 'class'.

Answer (score 7):

`books` is a pointer, who's size is 4. You can't read the size of your dynamically created "array".

You'll see that malloc works, when it doesn't return NULL.

Answer (score 3):

It prints 4 because that is the size of `books` (i.e. size of a pointer).

Answer (score 0):

alternative : You can use a array of struct BOOK, i.e. struct BOOK books[5000];

Comment: so how will i cast
books[]=malloc(sizeof(struct BOOK)*no);

Comment: you don't have to do that because books[5000] will allocate the memory